# How to return after get value from foreach in kotlin

Tags: java, android, for-loop, kotlin, foreach

I strucked here to return non null value to call my api. Please tell me how it will be work to call api for once, Thank you.

```
        barcodes.forEach {
            if (!it.displayValue.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                barCode = it.displayValue!!
            }   
        }
        if (barCode.isNotEmpty()) {
            viewModel.callMyAPI(barCode)
            stop()
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use the `find` method instead. It searches for an element satisfying a predicate, and stops looking when it finds it. If it doesn't find any element, it will return null.

Something like this:

```
val barCode = barcodes.find { !it.displayValue.isNullOrEmpty() }?.displayValue

if (barCode != null) {
    viewModel.callMyAPI(barCode)
    stop()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Continue in foreach:

   ```
   fun iterateForEach() {
           val listToTest = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
           listToTest.forEach {
              if (it == 5) return@forEach
                println(it)
   }
   }
   ```

2: Break in for each, use it inside run loop, it will execute

```
run loop@{
    listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).forEach {
        if (it == 3) return@loop // non-local return from the lambda passed to run
        println(it)
    }
}
```

I think you need 2 for your case.